# Set all margins/padding to 0, I'm still having problems with CSS layout

Tags: css

CSS beginner here, I'm at my wits end with a relatively simple css layout and was hoping someone would just look over it for me..

What i've got: [image]

CSS embedded temporarily, excuse the indenting (i've just come from programming and indenting was helping me make sense of it):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<style>

* {margin: 0; padding:0;}
body
{
    font: normal 100% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: LightSkyBlue;
    margin: auto auto;
    max-width: 90%; 
}

#central_container
{
    background-color: Yellow;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto auto;
    float: left;
}
#leftside_container
{
    background-color: Ivory;
    float: left;
    width: 66%; 
    clear: left;
}
    #header_container
    {
    background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15em;
    }
        #header_title
        {
            background-color: Lime;
            width: 100%;
            height: 80%;
        }
            #header_title h1{ padding: 0; margin: 0; }
            
        #navbar_container
        {
            background-color: Coral;
            width: 100%;
            height: 20%;
        }
            .navbar_links{ background-color: HotPink; }
            
        #currentpage_content
        {
            background-color: grey;
            width: 100%;
            height: 20%;
        }

#rightside_container
{
    background-color: Khaki;
    float: right;
    width: 33%; <!--/* 320 /960 */-->
}
    #register_container
    {
        background-color: LightPink;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #contacts_content
    {
        background-color: SeaGreen;
        width: 100%;
    }

</style>


<head>
    <title>Verge Green IT</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href"CSS/base.css" type="text/css" />
</head>


<body>
<div id="central_container">


    <!--Left-side Current-page Content-->
    <div id="leftside_container">
    
        <!--Header-->
        <div id="header_container">
        
            <div id="header_title">
            <h1>#header_title</h1>
            </div>
        
            <!--Navbar-->
            <div id="navbar_container"> 
            <div class="navbar_links">
            </div>
            </div>
        
        
        </div>
        <!--Current Page Contents-->
        <div id="currentpage_content">
            <p> #currentpage_content</p>
            <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p><p>
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
    <!--Right-side Every-page Content-->
    <div id="rightside_container">
        <div id="register_container"><p> #register_container </p></div>
        <div id="contacts_content"><p> #contacts_content</p></div>
    </div>
    
    
</div>
</body>


</html>
```

What i'm aiming for: [image]

(Vague text alternative: Where the register_container fills the rightside_container up to the height of the bottom of the navbar_container. And the contact_content fills up the rest of the rightside_container as the current_page content does on the leftside_container. )

I think i'm having some trouble because of the floating i'm trying to do.. and i have no idea why there's empty yellow space on the left of register_container/contacts_content. Nor why i can specify height for things like the header_title but not the register_container.

Really appreciate any help!

Comment: start with the width of the body, now is at 90% change it to 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some minor problems with values you have given in the Width and height field.

This works fine for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<style>

* {margin: 0; padding:0;}
body
{
    font: normal 100% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: LightSkyBlue;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 90%; 
    height: auto;
}

#central_container
{
    background-color: Yellow;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#leftside_container
{
    background-color: Ivory;
    float: left;
    width: 66%; 
    clear: left;
}
    #header_container
    {
    background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15em;
    }
        #header_title
        {
            background-color: Lime;
            width: 100%;
            height: 80%;
        }
            #header_title h1{ padding: 0; margin: 0; }

        #navbar_container
        {
            background-color: Coral;
            width: 100%;
            height: 20%;
        }
            .navbar_links{ background-color: HotPink; }

        #currentpage_content
        {
            background-color: grey;
            width: 100%;
            height: 20%;
        }

#rightside_container
{
    background-color: Khaki;
    float: right;
    width: 34%; <!--/* 320 /960 */-->
}
    #register_container
    {
        background-color: LightPink;
        width: 100%;
    height:240px;
    }
    #contacts_content
    {
        background-color: SeaGreen;
        width: 100%;
height:250px;
    }

</style>


<head>
    <title>Verge Green IT</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href"CSS/base.css" type="text/css" />
</head>


<body>
<div id="central_container">


    <!--Left-side Current-page Content-->
    <div id="leftside_container">

        <!--Header-->
        <div id="header_container">

            <div id="header_title">
            <h1>#header_title</h1>
            </div>

            <!--Navbar-->
            <div id="navbar_container"> 
            <div class="navbar_links">
            </div>
            </div>


        </div>
        <!--Current Page Contents-->
        <div id="currentpage_content">
            <p> #currentpage_content</p>
            <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p><p>
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!--Right-side Every-page Content-->
    <div id="rightside_container">
        <div id="register_container"><p> #register_container </p></div>
        <div id="contacts_content"><p> #contacts_content</p></div>
    </div>


</div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Ahh thank you i'll review all the changes so im clear on why it worked. One big question though, I'm trying to just use percent/em for scaling so that my site works on many screen resolutions. You're example specifies a pixel height for register_container and contacts_container, is there any way i can make the same layout with % / em?

Comment: you can use height:15em; instead of height: 240px;

Comment: Hey I've just looked a bit closer and with the code you provided (again thanks!) You can still see a 1px bit of blue showing through between the left and right side: http://imgur.com/ce89r . Any idea why? the left is 67% and the right 33% (they actually add up now ha), i changed the body width to 90% th

Comment: try this : #leftside_container
{
    background-color: Ivory;
    float: left;
    width: 67.1%; 
    clear: left;
}              #rightside_container
{
    background-color: Khaki;
    float: right;
    width: 33%; <!--/* 320 /960 */-->
}

Comment: perfect, thank you! (wouldn't have guessed the fix would be that simple Dx)